# ¿conectar otros usuario a la base de datos?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby

con mi grupo estamos trabajando mas bien aprendiendo a trabajar con rails y postgresql, el proyecto se subio a github , ellos lo descargaron pero al iniciar el server ( rails s) les sale que no tienen permiso de usuario en la base de datos.

**¿como puedo darles el permiso?**

esto les aparece

> FATAL: la autentificación Peer falló para el usuario «diegomaui»
>   Extracted source (around line #671):
>
> ## connected server's characteristics.          def connect            @connection = PGconn.connect(@connection_parameters)
>
> configure_connection          rescue ::PG::Error => error
>   if error.message.include?("does not exist")

Comment: Creo que hace falta mas información para poder llegar a una solución. Que hay acerca de tu configuracion de las conexiones a base de datos, la ubicacion del servidor (¿la base de datos se encuentra en el mismo equipo que sirve rails o se encuentra en un servidor en internet?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eso parece más un problema de PostgreSQL que de Ruby on Rails, lo más probable es que necesiten crear un usuario de PostgreSQL en el equipo local, desde una consola psql o desde PgAdmin pueden ejecutar: `CREATE USER diegomaui WITH PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4' CREATEDB;`, donde obviamente tienen que colocar el mismo password que aparece en `config/database.yml` de tu proyecto Ruby on Rails.

También tienes que asegurarte de tener configurado correctamente PostgreSQL, busca el archivo `pg_hba.conf`, en Ubuntu se encuentra en un directorio similar a `/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/pg_hba.conf`.

Luego que te encuentres a pg_hba.conf, cambia al final del archivo lo siguiente:

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5

host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

Por

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust

host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
```